# Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, testng

I Was Executing Test Scripts Though Excel Sheet Using Keyword Driven Data Framework.

While Executing Am Geting Error as :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot
>   get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell

My Selenium Code is

```
    package DemoData;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import DataConfig.ExcelDataConfig;

public class ReadArrayData 
{

    WebDriver driver;


  @Test(dataProvider="Tipreports")
  public void Dataprovider(String username, String password) throws InterruptedException
  {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe");

      driver = new ChromeDriver();

      driver.get("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/");

      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

      driver.manage().window().maximize();

      driver.findElement(By.id("txt_username")).sendKeys(username);

      driver.findElement(By.id("txt_pin")).sendKeys(password);

      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='btn_click']")).click();

      Thread.sleep(5000);

      //driver.getCurrentUrl();

      Assert.assertTrue(driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/Algorithm_Run.aspx"),"User Not able to Login - Invalid Credentials");   

  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void Close()
  {
      driver.quit();
  }

  @DataProvider(name="Tipreports")
  public Object[][] passdata()
  {

      ExcelDataConfig config = new ExcelDataConfig("E:\\Workspace\\KeywordFramework\\TestData\\Dataprovider.xlsx");
         int rows = config.getRowCount(0);

         Object[][] data = new Object[rows][2];

         for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
         {
             data[i][0]=config.getData(0, i, 0);
             data[i][1]=config.getData(0, i, 1);

         }
        return data;

  }

}
```

Here is My Excel Data Config Code :

```
package DataConfig;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelDataConfig 
{
    XSSFWorkbook wb;
    XSSFSheet Sheet1;

    public ExcelDataConfig(String excelpath)
    {
        try
        {
            File src = new File(excelpath);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
            wb= new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public String getData(int sheetnumber, int row, int column)
    {
        Sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(sheetnumber);

        String data =Sheet1.getRow(row).getCell(column).getStringCellValue();

        return data;

    }

    public int getRowCount(int sheetindex)
    {
        int row = wb.getSheetAt(sheetindex).getLastRowNum();

        row = row+1;

        return row;
    }

}
```

Can you please help me to sort out this, Why am getting this error? I have declared `2 Columns and 4 Rows` using for loop. But am getting cannot Get The error as cannot get the string value  from Numeic Cell.

Comment: Maybe not use `getStringCellValue()`? The error tells you exactly what the problem is

Comment: the cell holds a numeric value, and you try to get it as a string value: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getStringCellValue-- . use the cell type: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCellType--

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
String data;

if(cell.getCellType()==CellType.STRING) 
    data = cell.getStringCellValue(); 
else if(cell.getCellType()==CellType.NUMERIC) 
    data = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
else ...
```

It is a better way to retrieve the cell content as text.

Thanks to @AxelRichter, the manual show a more complete example to retrieve cell content: https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents

Comment: If the need is getting all cell contents as `String` using [DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) as shown in [Getting the cell contents](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents) will be best practice.

Comment: Thanks @spi , Your's Also Worked! Just Now i Got.

Answer (score 2):

```java
//try this:
DataFormatter objDefaultFormat = new DataFormatter();
FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
String cellValueStr = objDefaultFormat.formatCellValue( cell , formulaEvaluator );
```

Answer (score 2):

DataFormatter contains methods for formatting the value stored in an Cell. This can be useful when you need to get data exactly as it appears in Excel.
Supported formats include currency, SSN, percentages, decimals, dates, phone numbers, zip codes, etc.

Thanks to @AxelRichter:

```
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
String text = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
```